# issue with installing contact-form-7.3.1 in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress. I want to install this plugin in my wordpress site.I have downloaded it and activated it too. it generates code like

```
[contact-form-7 id="78" title="Contact form 1"]
```

I have write below code to display contact form ..

```
<?php  do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="78" title="Contact form 1"]');?>
```

but it does not display contact form. Can anyone suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="78" title="Contact form 1"]'); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php  do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="78" title="Contact form 1"]');?>
```

Comment: There is no need to modify code , you can do it from admin using POST or PAGE.

Comment: but He has used contact form plugin can we still do it from admin using POST or PAGE?

Comment: Yah , see this http://contactform7.com/faq/#How_can_I_add_a_contact_form_into_my_post_content

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `[contact-form-7 id="78" title="Contact form 1"]` code in your POST or PAGE you have created.

See this for more details.
http://contactform7.com/faq/#How_can_I_add_a_contact_form_into_my_post_content

Let me know if you need further help. Good luck.